# How to handle a results in a field where they could be NVARCHAR, FLOAT, or INT

Tags: sql-server, datatypes

I have a table that holds results. Based on what the `ResultTypeId` is these could be either `NVARCHAR`, `FLOAT`, or `INT`. In order to handle all these types the `Value` field is `NVARCHAR`

I've found that when handling the results I get problems. For example when trying to sum multiple `FLOAT` results I need to cast them to `FLOAT` first.

I think this is the wrong approach to storing the data. The only alternative I can think of is to create a value field for each data type, e.g.:
`ValueNumeric` `ValueText`.

***What is the recommended approach for this problem?***

Comment: Seems like the perfect use for sqlvariant...

Comment: @SeanGallardy - Sean, Aaron Bertrand tries to dissuade people from using Sqlvariant in this post - are Aaron's comments still valid today? - https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type

Comment: @ScottHodgin Oh, I never really condone the use of it.. however, I also don't condone terrible schemas either.. I'd still go with Aaron's recommendation but at the end of the day - this might be one place where they actually get a positive use out of it. *rant* I wish they would have never implemented it, personally.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your question is asking how you might define a table similar to your 'alternative', here is 'an' answer.

While I cannot tell you '*the recommended approach*', I can say we have a table that is very similar to your situation.  We can store different kinds of data depending on other criteria.  Our table definition is similar to what your '*alternative*' describes.

In our table, we have a column called DATA_TYPE CHAR(1) which identifies the type of data being stored.  I didn't design the table (as I would have opted for more than 1 character to identify the data type), but valid values are

- C (Character)
- D (Date)
- I (Integer)
- P (Decimal) - (it comes from a mainframe data type called packed-decimal)

*(In your situation, you might also define F-Float, B-Bit, etc.)*

We then have separate columns to hold the different data types

```
CREATE TABLE [SCFBDM].[CDB_AUDIT_LOG](
    [ENTITY_TYPE] [char](6) NOT NULL,
    [ENTITY_ID] [char](2) NOT NULL,
    [ENTITY_KEY] [datetime2](6) NOT NULL,
    [POLICY_NUMBER] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DEC_AMEND] [decimal](7, 3) NOT NULL,
    [ITEM] [datetime2](6) NOT NULL,
    [ENDORSEMENT] [char](6) NOT NULL,
    [ENDORSEMENT_ITEM] [datetime2](6) NOT NULL,
    [TABLE_OWNER] [char](8) NOT NULL,
    [TABLE_NAME] [char](18) NOT NULL,
    [ENTITY_OR_COLUMN] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [ENTITY_COLUMN_NAME] [char](18) NOT NULL,
    [ROW_TYPE] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [ACTION] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [OVERALL_EFFECT] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [ACCOUNT_NUMBER] [datetime2](6) NOT NULL,
    [DATA_TYPE] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [DATA_CHARACTER] [char](35) NULL,
    [DATA_DATE] [date] NULL,
    [DATA_DECIMAL] [decimal](11, 2) NULL,
    [DATA_INTEGER] [int] NULL,
    [USER_ID] [char](8) NULL
)
```